# Solving inequalities using sign patterns

Tags: inequality

I don't want the solution, I'm just confused as to what to do with the $e^x$ in this instance.

> Solve for $x$ in $e^x(2\cos x-1)≤0$ where $0≤x≤4\pi$.

Typically I would just reduce down to $\cos x ≤ \frac{1}{2}$ and then fill in the solutions for $x=\pi/3,5\pi/3,7\pi/3,11\pi/3$

Answer (score 1):

$e^x$ is always positive, so it does not contribute to the sign of the whole expression. In other words, you can simplify and only consider $$2\cos x - 1 \le 0. $$